# Помогите разобраться с InstantCMS

Tags: cms, instantcms

Сейчас занимаюсь изучением InstantCMS. Наткнулся на легкое непонимание ))
У меня есть сайт клиента, внешний вид сайта отличается от демо кардинально. Вот так выглядит админка сайта http://joxi.ru/ZrJbxpRCwBaolr . Не могу разобраться в причине таких отличий с версией демо http://joxi.ru/D2PlN8kcq57oK2   и не могу ни чего сделать на сайте в плане правок контента. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: у InstantCMS 2 версии: первый скрин админки версии 1.х, второй - версии 2.х

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за пояснение!